# How to solve the problem of Unknown field(s) (Id_card_number) specified for User?

Tags: python, html, django

I have code but whenever I `makemigrations`, it gives me error of `Unknown field(s) (Id_card_number) specified for User`. How to solve this issue?

*settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'firstapp.apps.FirstappConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

*models.py*

```
class User(forms.ModelForm):
    Id_card_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

*forms.py*

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)._unique = True
    Id_card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)._unique = True

    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields  =['username','email','password1','password2','Id_card_number']
```

Comment: You can try this: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.apps.User'`.

Comment: Now it is giving me ```ValueError: Invalid model reference 'users.apps.User'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.```

Comment: Will anyone answer?

Comment: I think in your User model you should extend a django model like: `class User(models.Model):` and use this model in your forms.py file.

Comment: You need to declare it in INSTALLED_APPS before `django.contrib.admin`

Comment: What I need to declare HenryM?

Comment: I used class ```User(AbstractUser)``` and ```class User(models.Model)``` but both are giving me ```Unknown field(s) (Id_card_number) specified for User```

Comment: Is there anyone?

Comment: In your form change the model in the Meta to [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model). Where you importing the wrong User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `models.py` is in an app called `users` (that's what you're saying in your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` declaration).  Rather than basing `User` on `forms.ModelForm`, it should be based on either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

You've started to create a custom user model but haven't followed through completely.  [Here](https://wsvincent.com/django-tips-custom-user-model/) is a good resource to learn about creating a custom user model, and below is a quick overview of creating a custom user model (I recommend inheriting from `AbstractUser`):

Within the `models.py` file in an app called `users`:

```
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    # add additional fields in here
```

And in your settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = users.CustomUser
```

The above declaration of `CustomUser` combined with telling Django that this is now the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` simply replicates Django's `auth` `User` model (no fields added yet in the above declaration).

Now, every place you might want to foreign key to your user model, you COULD do:

```
from users.models import CustomUser

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', ...)
```

HOWEVER, the better way to set up a FK to a custom user model is by reference - either:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), ...)
```

or

```
from django.conf import settings

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, ...)
```

Also, in `admin.py` your statement:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```

This statement is actually using the `User` model that is found in Django's `contrib.auth` app.  THAT user model does not have the `Id_card_number` and so I think that that is what's causing the error you're seeing.  Take note of Step 5 in the resource linked above - it will tell you how to set up things in `admin.py` for the `CustomUser` model.

[Further reference](https://wsvincent.com/django-referencing-the-user-model/)

Comment: Where to write ```user = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', ...)``` and what to write in those dots in both ```get_user_model``` and the above one? I didn't understand.

Comment: The ... is called an ellipsis, and it is used to indicate words that are left out.  In the spot where I placed the ellipsis, you would have to specify a value for `on_delete=` and you could, for instance, choose to put in `help_text="some help text"`.  The ellipsis just indicates where additional words would go.  The `user = models.ForeignKey(...)` would be a field on a model.  I was just showing you the different ways that you could write it.  I've updated the answer to show the different ways more clearly.